# restorecon fails with permission denied on ~user .ssh

Tags: linux, security, selinux

I discovered this when trying to do an ssh-copy-id. I was getting the error 'restorecon: could not set context for /home/rit/.ssh'.

The premissions look correct.

```
[rit@host ~]$ ls -ld .ssh 
drwx------. 2 rit COE 4096 Oct  3 08:02 .ssh
[rit@host ~]$ ls -l .ssh
total 16
-rw-------. 1 rit COE 1128 Oct  2 17:45 authorized_keys
-rw-------. 1 rit COE 2635 Sep 27 15:54 id_rsa
-rw-------. 1 rit COE  593 Sep 27 15:54 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--. 1 rit COE  180 Oct  2 15:58 known_hosts
```

The copy id seems to work but the error confuses our customers. I tried running restorecon -f directly on the files. I get no error on authorized keys, but do get the same error on .ssh. We are running Redhat 8.8.3 sceLinux with fips mode enabled.

Comment: Check the logs (use ssh -vv). It is possible that sshd configuration may prevent it, or as on some recent updates: old algorithms are no more accepted (so it depends on both ends)

Comment: "The permissions look correct" - but you're not checking the SELinux permissions - try `ls -lZ` (and expect a world of pain as you disappear down the SELinux rabbit hole)